# JsonConvert.PopulateObject not using JsonConverter class attribute

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

When trying to update the class properties using `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` the `JsonPathConverter` is not called and therefore populate is not done.

Sample class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
public class SampleClass
{
    int id;
    [JsonProperty("sample.id")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Call to `PopulateObject`:

```
var sampleClass = new SampleClass() {
    Id  = 1
};

var str = "{sample:{id:2}}";
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(str, sampleClass, new JsonSerializerSettings());
```

But the `Id` property never gets set to 2.

I've tried `JsonSerializerSettings` with `converter = new JsonPathConverter()` but it does not work either.

Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Note: I am assuming the `JsonPathConverter` you are referring to in your question is the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33094930/10263).*</sub>

`ReadJson` is only called on a `JsonConverter` when it is time to instantiate an object which is handled by the converter.  Since `PopulateObject` works on objects that are *already* instantiated, your converter's `ReadJson` method will not be called by `PopulateObject`.  This is by design.  If you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` instead of `JsonConvert.PopulateObject`, then the converter will be called as expected:

```
var sampleClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(str);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lxiirm

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it was only called when using DeserializeObject. But i really need to use populate (to update the properties of an existing object). Any idea on how to do that? I can use reflection to copy the values from one object to another, i'm just not sure if using populate would be faster or not...

Comment: Are there any update for this question. In Json.Net 13.0.1, ReadJson was pass existingValue parameter, is is use for Populate

Comment: Running into this problem in 2023, is there still no solution? I also need to use Populate, as I need control over how my object is constructed but still want to use all the out-of-the-box attribute functionality of Json.Net.

Why should it be this way? Why doesn't Populate account for [JsonConverter]? Why does this library still provide no way of invoking baseline deserialisation behaviour?