# Read JSON file and convert only specific tags to XML

Tags: c#, json, xml

I used newtonsoft to serialize an object to JSON.  Here is a record:

```
   "Properties": {
      "ProductId": "e2cba925-0720-465a-8c84-79626e9869e5",
      "LinkName": "link",
      "Brand": "brandx",
      "SiteActive": true,
      "RetailActive": true,
      "BaseColor": null,
      "BaseTextColor": null,
      "BackGroundImageId": null,
      "ProductGroupId": null,
      "MadeInUSAID": null
    },
    "Display": {
      "ProductId": "e2cba925-0720-465a-8c84-79626e9869e5",
      "ShowWeb": false,
      "ShowMobile": true,
      "ShowDatavault": true,
      "ShowDataVaultForPartners": true,
      "ShowNewsroom": false
    },
    "Image": {
      "ImageId": "e11ef84d-3c96-4fd9-a765-1f37e38ebc1a",
      "ImageThumbnailId": "dfd87a61-9d59-4a46-8895-541a21e73b39",
      "MD5": "3DECCFAA34946E1542BCCAD4DAC42CEC",
      "SHA": null,
      "SHA2_256": null,
      "SHA2_512": null,
      "DocumentType": null,
      "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
      "MaxWidth": null,
      "MaxHeight": null,
      "MaxResolution": null,
      "FileExtension": null,
      "FileName": "60144-1"
    },
    "ProductId": "e2cba925-0720-465a-8c84-79626e9869e5",
    "SKU": "60144",
    "ReceiptName": "blah blah blah",
    "UPC": "081483803371",
    "Taxable": true,
    "ColorId": "46a809ab-ac78-44f2-bd62-303345e9ff32",
    "ProductType": 1,
    "PackQty": 1
  },
  {
    "Description": {
      "ProductDescriptionId": "1b1d812b-0568-41a6-a0ed-4488c32b66e0",
      "ProductId": "2dc47c3e-7780-4768-bbae-6a1d6c4067ce",
      "LanguageId": 57,
      "Name": "widget 1",
      "TitleTag": "widget 1",
      "SEOText": null,
      "Description": null,
      "MetaDescription": null,
      "InternalKeywords": null
    }
```

I need to only pick certain fields from the JSON and put these values into an XML document. Looking around I see a lot of examples of converting the whole JSON to XML, but I only need specific tags.  Is there an example of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried exploring this library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moonmile.ExDoc.Json/

Comment: If you only need specific values, can't you just fetch them from your JSON, create the corresponding object to represent them and then XMLify that object?

Comment: I can create an object with the values I need, I just need to know how to fetch the values from the JSON into my object.  The JSON is used for multiple projects, I only need a sub set.  For example, I need Name, Brand. SKU, UPC, Description...as well as some others.  I am trying to get just those items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to overthink this.  What I did was deserialized the JSON back into the object, then looped through the object pulling the items I needed from the object instead of trying to go directly to the JSON:

```
  string jSonProducts = File.ReadAllText(settings.productJsonConfig.JSONProductFilePath);

        ICollection<ProductSearchModel> prods = null;
        prods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<ProductSearchModel>>(jSonProducts);
```

This gives me a strongly typed object to work with will reflect any changes to the JSON in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class that has all of the properties that you need:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string ImageId { get; set; } // just pick the ones you truly need
}
```

Then do the following in your parser logic:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myClassObject = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using (var sww = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, myClassObject);
        var xmlDocument = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
    }
}
```

Assuming that json is your json document that you posted in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Use @BrianRogers answer to my question, so you only have to take specific properties to map to your class:

[Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088462/can-i-specify-a-path-in-an-attribute-to-map-a-property-in-my-class-to-a-child-pr)

Answer (score 0):

You can try, [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library to read and write CSV /JSON/Xml files

Sample below shows how to extract 2 properties from JSON file and produce xml output

```
using (var reader = new ChoJSONReader("sample7.json")
    .WithField("ProductId", jsonPath: "$.Properties.ProductId", fieldType: typeof(string))
    .WithField("ImageId", jsonPath: "$.Image.ImageId", fieldType: typeof(string))
)
{
    using (var xWriter = new ChoXmlWriter("sample7.xml").WithXPath("Products/Product"))
        xWriter.Write(reader);
}
```

**Output Xml:**

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <ProductId>e2cba925-0720-465a-8c84-79626e9869e5</ProductId>
    <ImageId>e11ef84d-3c96-4fd9-a765-1f37e38ebc1a</ImageId>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Hope it helps your needs.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know.  This look promising thanks.