# Pick out specific, optional key from metavalues object in JSON and store into my class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm struggling to make this conversion happen, and not sure it's entirely feasible.  My JSON from a third party could look like this:

```
{
"equipments": [
    {
        "serialNumber": "11-17-053",
        "equipmentType_id": "589dda4952172110008870c7",
        "created": 1508856453875,
        "fieldOffice_id": "594af5425fbfca00111a0c20",
        "clients_id": [],
        "notes": "",
        "isInService": true,
        "metavalues": {
            "0t78nzhp9w265avlvt": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33121
                ]
            },
            "7ogz4kehqh8h3cwip8": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33128
                ]
            }
        },
        "schedules": [],
        "id": "59ef52854d40a9009c787596"
    },
    {
        "serialNumber": "11-17-054",
        "equipmentType_id": "589dda4952172110008870c7",
        "created": 1508856453875,
        "fieldOffice_id": "594af5425fbfca00111a0c20",
        "clients_id": [],
        "notes": "",
        "isInService": true,
        "metavalues": {
            "0t78nzhp9w265avlvt": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33121
                ]
            },
            "7ogz4kehqh8h3cwip8": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33128
                ]
            }
        },
        "schedules": [],
        "id": "59ef52854d40a9009c787597"
    },
    {
        "serialNumber": "8-17-022",
        "equipmentType_id": "589dda4952172110008870c7",
        "created": 1505326964589,
        "fieldOffice_id": "594af5425fbfca00111a0c20",
        "clients_id": [],
        "notes": "",
        "isInService": true,
        "metavalues": {
            "0t78nzhp9w265avlvt": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33121
                ]
            },
            "7ogz4kehqh8h3cwip8": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33128
                ]
            }
        },
        "schedules": [],
        "id": "59b9777480e426009d01d48d"
    },
    {
        "serialNumber": "22A-17-001",
        "equipmentType_id": "589dda4952172110008870c7",
        "created": 1504908025733,
        "fieldOffice_id": "58b74b080c206710004ff726",
        "clients_id": [
            "59bbfdf5725cd00012fb15d8"
        ],
        "notes": "",
        "isInService": true,
        "metavalues": {
            "0t78nzhp9w265avlvt": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33122
                ]
            },
            "7ogz4kehqh8h3cwip8": {
                "item_ids": [
                    33128
                ]
            },
            "g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l": "YARD",
            "709pm94prt2tpjt90y": 5,
            "bgen1h4i5b6f8xa1kh": "9/8/2017 7:18:24 PM",
            "yvtvsl8dedudqjtdud": "0.00000, 0.00000",
            "aj3h2b5fdbic9s72m3": "Parex",
            "8wt1re82xidjiv8rzi": "YARD"
        },
        "schedules": [],
        "id": "59b312f93256d5009c4a73fb"
    },....
```

This is obviously not a complete example, but should help get my question across.

Is there a way to create a C# class that pulls in certain fields only if they exist from the "metavalues" array?

My current class is as follows which works to get the data, but not exactly how I want.

```
public class Equipment
{
    [JsonProperty("serialNumber")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string equipmentType_id { get; set; }
    public bool isInService { get; set; }
    public List<string> clients_Id { get; set; }
    public string fieldOffice_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string EquipmentId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("metavalues")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> metavalues { get; set; } 
}
```

What I'm after, is taking the key of "g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l" which is optional in the metavalues, and store it in a property called "LeaseName".

I tried the following to no avail.

```
    public class Equipment
    {
        [JsonProperty("serialNumber")]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string equipmentType_id { get; set; }
        public bool isInService { get; set; }
        public List<string> clients_Id { get; set; }
        public string fieldOffice_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string EquipmentId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l")]
        public string LeaseName { get; set; }
    }
```

If I try to make a class for the metavalues section, I get an exception indicating that JSON.NET can't convert it to my object, hence why I used the `Dictionary<string, object>` option.

EDIT # 1:  The accepted answer works for me, but for those who stumble upon this and truly need a property name from a nested array you could try the following.

```
[OnDeserialized]
        private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            if (metavalues != null)
            {
                if (metavalues.ContainsKey("g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l"))
                {
                    string _LeaseName = (string)metavalues["g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l"];
                    LeaseName = _LeaseName;
                }
            }
        }
```

I think my edit approach is a bit overkill but just throwing this out there.

Comment: Try: `[JsonProperty("metavalues.g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l")]`

Comment: sorry but this did not work, the property was always null.

Comment: `[JsonProperty("metavalues.g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l", NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`

Comment: no luck here either.  Property is always null still.  I am using Version 10.0.0.0 of NewtonSoft.

Comment: @Fredou - good idea, these things move around a lot, but still a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but since the lease value is still one level down in the JSON you need an intermediate class to hold it (to replace the dictionary).

```
public class Equipment
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty("metavalues")]
    public MetaValues MetaValues { get; set; }
}

public class MetaValues
{
    [JsonProperty("g99idmcqyuo2na9e6l")]
    public string LeaseName { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ddqzc7

Comment: I made an edit just for further information on a different approach but I like your answer better for sure.

Comment: @ChrisFischer - you could also use `JsonPathConverter` from [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33094930)?