# Attribute to flatten serialisation of property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using C# and the NewtonSoft JSON package.

Lets say I've got an object with a property named `"MyProp"` which itself is a class with two properties, `"PropA"` and `"PropB"`. It by default it serialises like so:

`{
  "MyProp": 
  {
    "PropA": 1
    "PropB": 2
  }
}`

I want it to serialise like this:

`{
  "PropA": 1
  "PropB": 2
}`

Is there anything I can tag `"MyProp"` with that will achieve this? Or if I have to write my own `JsonConverter`, is there a somewhat painless method of doing this?

Comment: You will need a custom `JsonConverter` to do this.  See [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33088462/10263), which is similar but talks about deserialization.  Have a look at [Christiano Santos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047126/10263) which shows how to implement the `WriteJson` method of the converter so that it works for serialization as well.  I have not tested his solution, but it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can tag the class with any attributes to get this. A way to achieve what you want is to Serialize to an anonymous type:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {PropA = myProp.PropA, PropB = myProp.PropB});
```

This will give you what you want for small use cases like this but will become quite tedious for larger classes.