# Deserialize Json Nested Object to a class level property instead of a class object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Deserializing json Nested Objects to class properties instead of a class object

well I just want json deserializer do deserialize directrly to my `FlatClassModel` instead of serializing it to the `ClassModel` and then map it by hand

look at the following code for example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    // assume we have a given json
    var Json =  @"{
  'ClassLevelProperty': 'Class Level Values',
  'NestedModel': {
    'FirstNestedProperty': 'First Nested value',
    'AnotherNestedProperty': 'Another Nested Value'
                  }
               }";

    var classModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassModel>(Json);
    var flatclassModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlatClassModel>(Json);

    Console.Write(classModel.ClassLevelProperty + " ... " + classModel.NestedModel.FirstNestedProperty + " ... " + classModel.NestedModel.AnotherNestedProperty);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write(flatclassModel.ClassLevelProperty + " ... " + flatclassModel.FirstNestedProperty + " ... " + flatclassModel.AnotherNestedProperty);

  }
}
    class ClassModel
    {
        public string ClassLevelProperty { get; set; }
        public NestedModel NestedModel { get; set; }
    }
    public class NestedModel
    {
        public string FirstNestedProperty { get; set; }
        public string AnotherNestedProperty { get; set; }

    }

    public class FlatClassModel
    {
        public string ClassLevelProperty { get; set; }
        public string FirstNestedProperty { get; set; }
        public string AnotherNestedProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Tip: A handy way to try the code goto https://try.dot.net/ paste and run

Comment: well , this is mainly for parsing send grid events and want store them in one  DatabaseTable , so it make sense to me to do it in one operation instead of Deserializing then mapping (There could be alot of data to process),
@CodeCaster does that make sense?

Comment: You can use the `JsonPathConverter` solution from [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33088462/10263).  See fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c49Egk) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want json deserializer do deserialize directrly to my FlatClassModel

Why? The model must match the JSON in order to successfully deserialize. Imagine `AnotherNestedProperty` to exist on the root level *and* on a deeper level, which one do you want to be populated? And why?

So either create a conversion from one type to the other:

```
var flattened = new FlatClassModel
{
    ClassLevelProperty = classModel.ClassLevelProperty,
    FirstNestedProperty = classModel.NestedModel.FirstNestedProperty,
    AnotherNestedProperty = classModel.AnotherNestedProperty,
};
```

Or create read-only properties:

```
public class ClassModel
{
    public string ClassLevelProperty { get; set; }

    public string FirstNestedProperty => NestedModel.FirstNestedProperty;
    public string AnotherNestedProperty => NestedModel.AnotherNestedProperty;

    public NestedModel NestedModel { get; set; }
}
```