# Serialize C# class into nested JSON with specified paths in JsonProperty attribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have flat C# class with lots of properties and I want to serialize an instance of that class into JSON using Json.NET. While serializing, I need to produce a JSON string that is nested. I know that I can create subclasses to achieve this but this is unnecessary overhead.

Let's assume I have this class:

```
public class MyClass{
  [JsonProperty("subgroupa.myotherproperty")]
  public int MyProperty {get;set;} = 5;
}
```

How can I get this JSON:

```
{
  "subgroupa": {
     "myotherproperty": 5
   }
}
```

In the past, I was able to deserialize such a nested JSON string into a flat object. Therefore, I believe Json.NET can also do the opposite.

Comment: I think I found a customized solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41522391/225808  Is there anything build into Json.NET?

Answer (score -1):

```
    using System.Text.Json; 

    public class MyClass{
        [JsonProperty("subgroupa.myotherproperty")]
        public int MyProperty {get;set;} = 5;}

  string subgroupa = JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyClass);
```

Comment: This produces a flat JSON result on my computer, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry about that- even if MyProperty is defined as its own object with one attribute, called value?