# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject - Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonconverter

I am trying to map the JSON nodes to my class using path and get an error when DeserializeObject. Error is thrown at JObject.Load(reader).

```
'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

Here is Json response;

```
var responseData = "[{\"Channels\":[{\"Channel\":55,\"DataRate\":60,\"Offset\":0,\"PreScaled\":{\"Flags\":null,\"Reading\":4.809,\"ValidPercentage\":100},\"RedactedPercentage\":0,\"Scaled\":{\"Flags\":null,\"Reading\":4.809,\"ValidPercentage\":100},\"SensorLabel\":\"FLOW\",\"SensorName\":\"Flow\",\"Slope\":1,\"UniqueId\":685100,\"UnitName\":\"Litres Per Minute\"},{\"Channel\":57,\"DataRate\":60,\"Offset\":0,\"PreScaled\":{\"Flags\":null,\"Reading\":60.43,\"ValidPercentage\":100},\"RedactedPercentage\":0,\"Scaled\":{\"Flags\":null,\"Reading\":60.43,\"ValidPercentage\":100},\"SensorLabel\":\"HUM\",\"SensorName\":\"Humidity\",\"Slope\":1,\"UniqueId\":685100,\"UnitName\":\"Percent\"}],\"Location\":{\"Altitude\":null,\"Latitude\":52.20175,\"Longitude\":-1.7266},\"Timestamp\":{\"Convention\":\"TimeBeginning\",\"Timestamp\":\"2023-05-29T10:23:00+00:00\"}},{\"Channels\":[{\"Channel\":55,\"DataRate\":60,\"Offset\":0,\"PreScaled\":{\"Flags\":null,\"Reading\":4.803,\"ValidPercentage\":100},\"RedactedPercentage\":0,\"Scaled\":{\"Flags\":null,\"Reading\":4.803,\"ValidPercentage\":100},\"SensorLabel\":\"FLOW\",\"SensorName\":\"Flow\",\"Slope\":1,\"UniqueId\":685100,\"UnitName\":\"Litres Per Minute\"}],\"Location\":{\"Altitude\":null,\"Latitude\":52.20175,\"Longitude\":-1.7266},\"Timestamp\":{\"Convention\":\"TimeBeginning\",\"Timestamp\":\"2023-05-29T10:22:00+00:00\"}}]";

ReferenceStationData jsonLatestData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReferenceStationData>(responseData, new JsonSerializerSettings{DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc});
```

```cs
    
    //holds the desired deserialization logic
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        object targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            string jsonPath = att != null ? att.PropertyName : prop.Name;
            if (serializer.ContractResolver is DefaultContractResolver)
            {
                var resolver = (DefaultContractResolver)serializer.ContractResolver;
                jsonPath = resolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(jsonPath);
            }

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(jsonPath, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$"))
            {
            //throw new InvalidOperationException($"JProperties of JsonPathConverter can have only letters, numbers, underscores, hiffens and dots but name was ${jsonPath}."); // Array operations not permitted
            }

            JToken token = jo.SelectToken(jsonPath);
            if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
            {
                object value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                prop.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
            }
        }

        return targetObj;
    }
```

Here is my code example;

https://dotnetfiddle.net/wEUZ83

Comment: Are you looking for something like `JsonPathConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33094930) by Brian Rogers to [Can I specify a path in an attribute to map a property in my class to a child property in my JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33088462)?  Or rather, did you base your code on that answer?  If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: Post your code in the question itself. The error suggests you're trying to deserialize the array into an object, eg `Product` instead of an array or  list of objects, eg `List<Product>` or `Product[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the target type to an array or list, eg:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};
var stations= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReferenceStationData[]>(
    responseData, 
    settings);
```

`DeserializeObject` will deserialize the data to the exact type you specify. You need to tell it to handle the JSON string as an array or object by specifying the correct type.