# Converting List<MyClass> to JSON fails

Tags: c#, list, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to convert a list of my objects to a JSON array (wrapped in a JSON object) but keep getting an error that I have no idea what is being caused by.

My class for objects on the list:

```
public class BriefResponseTestingDto
{
    public Guid GrantId { get; set; }
    public string GrantName { get; set; }
}
```

My code serializing the list to JSON:

```
List<BriefResponseTestingDto> list = new List<BriefResponseTestingDto>();
list.Add(new BriefResponseTestingDto() { GrantId = new Guid(), GrantName = "Name1"});
list.Add(new BriefResponseTestingDto() { GrantId = new Guid(), GrantName = "Name2"});
list.Add(new BriefResponseTestingDto() { GrantId = new Guid(), GrantName = "Name3"});

dataAsJobject = new JObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list));
```

After serializing, I try to convert the string to JObject and I get an exception thrown with the message:
**Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.  That will return a json string, you don't need to put that into a `JObject`.

Comment: @John, Newtonsoft's Json.NET doesn't seem to have a JObject.From() method.

Comment: I bet you don't even need to convert it as JObject

Answer (score 1):

When you want to serialize to string do this:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

To convert back, do this:

```
var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BriefResponseTestingDto>>(jsonString);
```

Since you serialized a `List`, that is an array and it won't work with `JObject`. I would suggest an even more generic `JToken` that handles all cases. If you must work with it in it's current form, use `JArray`.

```
var myjObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonString);
```

---

Based on my conversion with OP, the want to be able to add an array to an existing object. There are a couple ways to do this, but I tend to always fall back to the `dynamic` route.

Let's say we have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "hello":"world"
}
```

and we want to add an array as a sibling to the property `hello` so it looks like this:

```
{
    "hello":"world",
    "myArray":[1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

We can accomplish this by taking the original model and converting it to `dynamic`. Since we are tightly coupled to `Newtonsoft`, I am going to take advantage of that by letting that library do the heavy lifting.

Here is a method to convert an object to an `ExpandoObject` type `dynamic` that allows you to some pretty neat things:

```
public static dynamic ConvertObjectToExpandoObject(object obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, leaveOpen: true))
        using (var jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            new JsonSerializer().Serialize(jtw, obj);
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = { new ExpandoObjectConverter() }
            }).Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(jtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that it is `dynamic` and it understands `ExpandoObject` semantics, we can add any property as any type to it:

```
var myDynamic = ConvertObjectToExpandoObject(new { hello = "world" });
myDynamic.myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDynamic);
```

You could use any model you want here, even concrete models (not just anonymous object). We added an array to it, then serialized it back. It will now look like the result from above that we wanted.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);` throws exception "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'."

Comment: @Val -- sorry, forgot we were working with `List`. `JObject` is an object, not an array. You need to use `JArray`. Will update my answer. Why do you need to just `J-Anything`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to insert my array into a property in a JSON object: `{ "data": [ item1, item2, item3] }`

Comment: @Val  -- updated answer to show you how I add properties to existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `JValue`, `JArray` or another `JObject` into a `JObject` directly; you need to put it into a `JProperty` (which has a name) and add *that* to the `JObject`.  That is why you are getting the error you are seeing.  Also, you should use `JArray.FromObject` to convert your list to a `JArray` before adding it to the `JProperty`.  If you use `SerializeObject()` you will wind up with a string value instead, which is not what you want here.  See [Can Json.Net handle a List<object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1208030/10263) for more explanation on that.

So you would have:

```
var dataAsJobject = new JObject(new JProperty("data", JArray.FromObject(list)));
var json = dataAsJobject.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eYMLVV

You could also get your desired output using an anonymous object instead:

```
var anon = new { data = list };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anon, Formatting.Indented);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGxvwf